# I want to push element in to array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I want to get all input field which have value have this format

```
"name": [{
  "id": 3,
  "qty": 2
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "qty": 5
}]
```

**`My script`**

```
$("#qty-"+item.id).keyup(function(){
                            var qty = $("#qty-"+item.id).val();
                            var price = $("#price-"+item.id).val();
                            var ids = $("#ids-"+item.id).val();
                            var total = qty * price;
                            $("#amount-"+item.id).val(total);
                            var obj={};
                            var name = [];
                            obj.id = ids;
                            obj.qty = qty;
                            name.push(obj);
                            console.log(name);
                            /* Sum of Total of all amount */
                                var add = 0;
                                $(".amount").each(function() {
                                    add += Number($(this).val());
                                });
                                console.log(add);
                                $("#aproxTotal").text("Aprox Total is : " + add);
                            /* Sum of Total of all amount */
                        });
```

In console i got only last enter value only in this way

**`output`**

```
0:
id:"14"
qty:"1"
```

How to get all filed only have value. If i use each function it will show all even empty field also

**`My HTML given Below`**

```
    <div id="price-calculation-view">
   <div id="price_calculation">
      <div class="col-lg-2 main"><input type="text" value="Newspaper" readonly="" class="form-control"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 main"><input type="text" name="price" id="price-3" value="9" readonly="" class="form-control" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 main"><input type="text" value="" name="qty" id="qty-3" class="form-control qty" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 main"><input type="text" name="amount" id="amount-3" value="" readonly="" class="form-control amount" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 main"><input type="text" name="id" id="ids-3" value="3" readonly="" class="form-control"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="price_calculation">
      <div class="col-lg-2 main"><input type="text" value="Cardboards (flattened)" readonly="" class="form-control"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 main"><input type="text" name="price" id="price-4" value="5" readonly="" class="form-control" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 main"><input type="text" value="" name="qty" id="qty-4" class="form-control qty" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 main"><input type="text" name="amount" id="amount-4" value="" readonly="" class="form-control amount" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 main"><input type="text" name="id" id="ids-4" value="4" readonly="" class="form-control"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="price_calculation">
      <div class="col-lg-2 main"><input type="text" value="Glass Bottles (Unbroken)" readonly="" class="form-control"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 main"><input type="text" name="price" id="price-5" value="0.4" readonly="" class="form-control" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 main"><input type="text" value="" name="qty" id="qty-5" class="form-control qty" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 main"><input type="text" name="amount" id="amount-5" value="" readonly="" class="form-control amount" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 main"><input type="text" name="id" id="ids-5" value="5" readonly="" class="form-control"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="price_calculation">
      <div class="col-lg-2 main"><input type="text" value="Plastic bottles" readonly="" class="form-control"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 main"><input type="text" name="price" id="price-6" value="11" readonly="" class="form-control" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 main"><input type="text" value="" name="qty" id="qty-6" class="form-control qty" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 main"><input type="text" name="amount" id="amount-6" value="" readonly="" class="form-control amount" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 main"><input type="text" name="id" id="ids-6" value="6" readonly="" class="form-control"></div>
   </div>

</div>
```

Values are comming from api dynamically How to achieve this ??

Comment: please provide html code also for better answer. link: http://www.jsonwrapper.com/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=tags&utm_campaign=queries

Comment: This is a little difficult to understand due to what I assume is a language barrier. Please elaborate and show examples.

Comment: Check my updated question

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your var holding hash array is not global, so everytime you do var name = [] it resets it.

Put var name = [] outside keyup function.

```
var name = [];

$("#qty-"+item.id).keyup(function(){
                        var qty = $("#qty-"+item.id).val();
                        var price = $("#price-"+item.id).val();
                        var ids = $("#ids-"+item.id).val();
                        var total = qty * price;
                        $("#amount-"+item.id).val(total);
                        var obj={};
                        obj.id = ids;
                        obj.qty = qty;
                        name.push(obj);
                        console.log(name);
                        /* Sum of Total of all amount */
                            var add = 0;
                            $(".amount").each(function() {
                                add += Number($(this).val());
                            });
                            console.log(add);
                            $("#aproxTotal").text("Aprox Total is : " + add);
                        /* Sum of Total of all amount */
                    });
```

See the fiddle, you just need to adapt it! https://jsfiddle.net/zqxn5gzf/

Comment: Sorry, i mistaked it, it's keyup function. I will edit.

Comment: Still same only it not show all entered value it wil show current value only

Comment: Ajax just return the value of text box that's it

Comment: It's the same thing, you are initializing add inside keyup function. All the info you need to propagate needs to be initialized outside the function.

Comment: How to use outside and get all value in that format

Comment: We need more info. Where do you get from item.id? You need to provide us https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: I have custom Api If i hit i will get all those details

Comment: Ok, see this fiddle. I just adjusted to test, it sums up right. But i just used 2 inputs, you just need to update that part of the code, but it works!

https://jsfiddle.net/zqxn5gzf/

Comment: Hey I got a same out put for mine also

Comment: Let say if i enter 1st text box i got some value then if i enter 2nd textbox i want previous value and current textbox value

Comment: This is whats happening at the fiddle, i tested, it's suming up, but i only did bind two inputs understand? Im not doing your whole work, you need to understand and replicate.